# Speed up javascript gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a simple-ish javascript gallery and it's performing slow when I have more than 3 or 4 images in it. Don't get confused, I don't mean that it is going to the next image slowly, I mean that its jagged and not smooth when going to the next image. Is there a way to make the code more optimized to be smoother? or perhaps better functions in javascript that are quicker? I'm not sure what to look for as I just recently begun to look into javascript.

I have already compressed all the pictures to less than 300kb each. The code is bellow, both the javascript and html

```
//javascript
<script>
function slideSwitch() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 41) - 25;

    var active = $("div#slideshow img.active");
    active.siblings().css({'z-index': 97});
    active.next().css({
        'z-index': 98,
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
        'transform': 'rotate(0deg)'
    });
    active.css({ 'z-index': 99 });
    if(active.hasClass('last')){
        active.siblings(":first").css({ 'z-index': 98,
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
        'transform': 'rotate(0deg)' });
    }


    active.animate({ "left": (350+600) }, 250).css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + r + 'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + r + 'deg)',
        'transform': 'rotate(' + r + 'deg)'
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        active.css({ 'z-index': 97 });
        active.removeClass('active');
        if (active.hasClass("last")) {
            active.siblings(":first").addClass('active');
        } else {
            active.next().addClass('active');
        }
        active.animate({ "left": 350 }, 150);
    }, 250);
}

$(function () {
    setInterval("slideSwitch()", 1000);
});
```

```
<!--HTML-->
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="picture/img1.jpg" style="position:absolute;" class="active" />
    <img src="picture/img2.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img src="picture/img3.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img src="picture/img4.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img src="picture/img5.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img src="picture/img6.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img src="picture/img7.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img src="picture/img8.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img src="picture/img9.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img src="picture/img10.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img src="picture/img11.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img src="picture/img12.jpg" style="position:absolute;" class="last"/>
</div>
```

Thanks all.

Comment: What do you mean by "slow"? The performance in the browser? I'm on Chrome and it works pretty well: http://jsfiddle.net/Xs9R6/1/ One could optimize the jquery selector: `$('.active', '#slideshow');`

Comment: @Imperative: is `$('.active', '#slideshow');` really an optimization/improvement?

Comment: If a browser supports `transform` then it almost certainly supports `transition` as well. So why bother with `.animate()`?

Comment: @zeroflagL See my provided fiddle, the selector works flawlessly and notice my explenation answer below.

Comment: okay sure it does appear to go faster on the fiddle... except that those images are 3kb big... mine are 100x bigger at 300kb. It goes to reason that it would be quicker regardless of the optimized selector or not. But it is quicker, so thanks for that :)

Comment: @zeroflagL is transition part of javascript or css? how would I modify my code to use transition instead? I would like to test and see if its better

Comment: `transition` is CSS only. You can find an introduction [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions). Basically the animation happens automatically when you change a property of an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to use CSS3 transitions with fallbacks to jQuery if you want smoother animations. jQuery is limited by javascript's performance while CSS3 uses the computers GPU to speed things up. There are plugins out there that do this automatically for you. [Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) for example is one of them. Or you can manually do it by setting `transition: left 500ms ease` on the slide elements and then changing position using `$.css` instead of `$.animate`. If you do it manually you'll probably want to use something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect CSS3 transition support and switch accordingly.

You could also try lowering [jQuery.fx.interval](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/) although I doubt it would make a difference. The default value is 13ms which is approximately 76 frames a second. Plenty fast for smooth animations.

Answer (score 3):

@Both guys asking for my selector (in the question comment): take into note, that the jquery selector engine (sizzle) reads selectors from right to left. so in the original selector (`"div#slideshow img.active"`) it would look for all elements with class `.active`, then continue with those, that are an `img` tag. than proceed to look for the id, which must be a div. Look at this <kbd>[jsperf](http://jsperf.com/optimizing-jquery-1-9-0-selectors)</kbd> to see the difference in performance for selecting `div.foobar` vs. `.foobar`.
The selector i provided fetches the id first, which is the fastest way of selecting an DOM element in jquery. Then it looks for sub elements of the id, which have the `.active` class. Note that the selector goes `$('.foobar', '#id')` , **not** `$('.foobar, #id')` see the difference. There is some info on this in the <kbd>[jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)</kbd>.

Comment: This should make it into a Hall Of jQuery Fame. So few people are aware of this. Good job pointing it out.

Comment: "Note that the selector goes $('.foobar', '#id') , not $('.foobar, #id')" - I can't believe I missed that. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be answer you are looking for now, but jQuery animate is a little slow in general (compared to other solutions). On a project I experimented with gsap for my animations. It seemed to work a lot smoother and the syntax is pretty easy to learn. Rewriting the animations only took me about half an hour, but I understand if you don't feel like it, however it might be an consideration in the future otherwise.

[GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/)

ps. I wouldn't recommend the jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in using jQuery for this. You are animating CSS transforms, this means that the browser will already have support for CSS animations and transitions. Use them and your animation will be smooth.
Don't use setTimeout, use instead requestAnimationFrame if you wish to do this by Javascript.